# Is possible convert BitmapDescriptor to Bitmap?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, bitmap

I need to convert BitmapDescriptor to Bitmap.

I can convert a bitmap to BitmapDescriptor with this code:

```
BitmapDescriptor bd = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
```

but how can i do the inverse way ?

I need to get `BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker()` in bitmap format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I m not sure but I don't think so it is possible

In my application i have requirement to change default market color ...i got the default marker as bitmap using below code hope it helps u

```
Drawable d = DrawableUtils.resizeImageToDrawable(
                    MapViewFragment.mapViewActivity,
                    Configuration.Display.getDrawableFix(i),
                    Configuration.MapView.getWaypointIconWidth(),
                    Configuration.MapView.getWaypointIconHeight());
d.setColorFilter(color, Mode.MULTIPLY);

Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) d).getBitmap();
Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas(b);

int myColor = b.getPixel(0,0);
ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter(myColor, color);
```

If any questions u can ask

Comment: The library "import android.support.v7.widget.DrawableUtils;" dont have resizeImageToDrawable. With lib are you using ?