# How to convert bitmapDescriptor to bitmap?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Feature I am trying to implement is: enlarge marker with specific icon if it is the closest one to user's selected area. I store all markers in one collection collectionOfMarkers() and findClosest() method returns marker that is closest to user's area.

```
// Get closes marker
        closestMarker= getClosestItem(collectionOfMarkers(),latLng);
        mClusterRenderer.getMarker(closestMarker).setIcon(closestMarker.getIcon());
```

To resize that one marker I would need to pass new Bitmap with specified width and height parameters, however it also would need Bitmap source and I only have bitmapDescriptor from doing closestMarker.getIcon(). Is there a way to convert BitmapDescriptor to Bitmap? I do not have icon name or resource path, as there are multiple icons that marker could represent from, thus, it has to be extracted from marker itself.

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44120121/is-possible-convert-bitmapdescriptor-to-bitmap

Comment: no, you cannot do that

Comment: Why not just have a separate resource which is the "closest" icon and use that from the BitmapDescriptorFactory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Bitmap resizeMapIcons(String iconName,int width, int height){
    Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),getResources().getIdentifier(iconName, "drawable", getPackageName()));
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, width, height, false);
    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

Use it like

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("New Marker")
            .snippet("Check out this place.")
            .position(chelsea).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(resizeMapIcons("image_name",100,100))));
```

Comment: That's the thing, if I had an icon name I would use this, but I need to get icon from marker itself and then resize it, as there are multiple icons that can be used on that marker. My bad, I will edit this into my question

Comment: I always have marker in my list item to reuse it. same you can hold your resource id for further use.

Comment: did not think of that, I did put it in. But just out of curiosity and lack of understanding of these Bitmaps. If we use BitmapDescriptor as an actual representation of image, why it is not possible to convert it back to Bitmap

Comment: Currently i can not see a satisfying way to convert BitmapDescriptor to Bitmap